# Take first elements of 'xs' that are equal to 'a' without using takeWhile

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I want to write a function `f :: a -> [a] -> [a]` such that `f a xs` is a list containing the first elements of `xs` that are equal to `a`, such that if `xs` does not start with `a` the list is empty. Specific cases will make this clearer:

```
f 3 [3, 3, 2, 1, 3] = [3, 3]
f 3 [1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3] = []
f 3 [1, 2, 5] = []
f "a" "aaaFS" = "aaa"
f "a" "elephant" = ""
```

My issue is with making the recursion *stop* when a value `x != a` is found. Which makes me think recursion itself might not be the best way to approach this.

In other words, while it is easy to write a function that takes all `a`'s from `xs`, such that `f' 1 [1, 1, 2, 2, 1] = [1, 1, 1]`, I don't know how to write a function that takes only the initial `a`'s from `xs`; this is, an `f` such that `f 1 [1, 1, 2, 2, 1] = [1, 1]`.

Comment: with recursion.

Comment: How would you write it with `takeWhile`?

Comment: I don't mean to be offensive but that is not a very helpful comment. I literally said "my issue is with making the recursion stop (...)". How would I understand how to make the recursion stop with a comment saying "with recursion"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for the hint! I'll write it with takeWhile first.

Comment: You stop the recursion by adding a case that does not make a recursive call, e.g. return an empty list

Comment: @JonasHøgh this was the clearest and more straight-forward answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion here. Indeed, as with a lot of list processing, you can work with:

```
f :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
f y = go
    where go [] = …
          go (x:xs) = …
```

For the filter-like function, this looks like:

```
filter' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
filter' y = go
    where go [] = []
          go (x:xs) | x == y = x : go xs
                    | otherwise = go xs
```

You will here have to prevent recursing if we found an element that is not equal. I leave this as an exercise.